# .htaccess Redirect based on HTTP_REFERER

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-referer

I'm trying to do what I've said above but I am getting a looping error and sometimes a 500 error!

What I want is for users requesting the root 'Home' page of the site to be redirected to `/Welcome` - UNLESS they are already browsing the site.

Here's my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^mydomain\.co\.uk$ [N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php [N]
RewriteRule ^$ /Welcome [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting the 500 error because the `[N]` isn't a valid `RewriteCond` flag, are you thinking of `[NC]` (no case)?

Additionally, you have a condition that directly contradicts the rule's match:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php
```

Says the **URI** must have a `/index.php` in it. While the rule itself:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /Welcome [L]
```

Says the **URI** must match `^$` which means it must be exactly `/`. And `/` will never be `/index.php`, so the rule is instantly invalid. Maybe you're thinking of either/or?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^mydomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /Welcome [L]
```

This will match the referer without case against `mydomain.co.uk`, and rewrite either `/` or `/index.php` to `/Welcome`