# Redirect all traffic to from external domain to local domain homepage?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, seo, http-referer

There is an external website which is redirecting all its traffic to webpages on our site. We can't control this redirection and the content URLs are mirrored in the following way.

When users go to:

```
www.externaldomain.com/1234
```

they get redirected to:

```
www.ourdomain.com/1234
```

which can sometimes be a non-existant page and thus a 404 error results. How can I re-direct all traffic from `externaldomain.com` to `ourdomain.com` homepage to make sure we don't lose potential users?

I know `HTTP_REFERER` comes into play, but I'm having trouble setting it up getting it to function properly.

Comment: You might be a better question for  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you trying to re-direct pages that only result in a 404 or all referred pages?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618445/htaccess-redirect-based-on-http-referer)

You must use modrewrite of apache:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^mydomain.co.uk$ [N]

Comment: This one doesn't work actually for me. I guess this code is for a bit another case.

Answer (score 0):

The most important question to ask here is whether you wish to redirect all traffic to your homepage or specific pages that you've mentioned 'sometimes' don't exist (404) - both of which which are answered here.

**Redirecting all referred traffic to a homepage from a specific external domain**

Where you need to redirect all traffic from a specific domain (referrer), you can do the following:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://externaldomain\.com/ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [R=301,L]
```

**Redirecting only 404 error traffic to a homepage from a specific domain**

If you want to redirect on this basis then use:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://externaldomain\.com/ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [R=301,L]
```

With regard to the apache flags noted above:

```
 [NC]    = No case (or case insensitive)
 [L]     = If the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.
 [R=301] = Apply a 301 redirect*
```

You can find more verbose/detailed info on Apache flags [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html).

***Search engine optimisation for these rules**

Why a 301 redirect? - A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which passes more than 90+% of link juice (or potential *ranking power*) to the redirected page. 301 refers to the HTTP status code for this type of redirect. In most instances, the 301 redirect is the best method for implementing redirects on a website in terms of SEO. In terms of benefit, there is a wealth of information [here](http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) on how to capitalise on and deal with different types of redirect.

Comment: Hello nickhar, thanks a lot for an explanation, actually my case is number 1: Redirecting all referred traffic to a homepage from a specific external domain, however your code doesn't work for me. It doesn't redirect to frontpage, my full htaccess looks like this http://pastebin.com/sBAzM0jr