# Node.js and Angular routing - How to make REST API inaccessible by browser URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, angular-ui-router

I use Angulars `$http` service to call for data on the backend. Let's say JSON data. An example URL to do so would be something like:

```
/get/data
```

Doing this from within Angular nicely returns the requested data. No problem.

But even though I catch **all other** Angular routes using Angular UI Router with `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');`, I can still go to my browser and type in the `mydomain.com/get/data` URL, which provides me with a page of JSON code.

How to I restrict back-end server calls to come just from Angular, NOT from my browser URL without user authentication?

**N.B.**
Using Express 4.X on Node, I also provided my app with a 'catch-all' route to default back to my front-end index.html page, like so:

```
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at PassportJS. That will get you started.

Comment: I'm familiar with passport, but since there's not authentication level, I was wondering if it could be fixed otherwise than adding a complete new security layer to the application.

Comment: Authentication is exactly what you need - no escaping it I'm afraid

Comment: Thanks for putting your efforts, I'll give it a try with authentication then!

Comment: The closest you can get to this without authentication is having your angular app send a custom header, and requiring that header on the backend. However, that can of course be spoofed by anyone trying to get to the raw data. Plus, the raw data is easily available in the network tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My God! Spent whole frikin day fighting this problem, finally fixed it!
The dog is burried in headers - you have to specify one on Angular http request, then read it in node.

First of - routing setup is the same as in this guide: https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application

On frontend in Angular http request I specify one of the accepted header types to be json:

```
$http.get('/blog/article', { 
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;'
    }
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
```

On backend in Node I check if header includes json type. If it does, I serve back json data, so angular can receive the content. If it doesn't, I force node to load index.html, from which the controller runs the before mentioned http request with the header, ensuring you get your data then.

```
app.get('/blog/article', function(req, res) {

if(/application\/json;/.test(req.get('accept'))) {
    //respond json
    //console.log("serving json data...");
    blogItemModel.find({ "_id" : req.query.id }, 'title full_text publish_date', function(err, blog_item){
        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(blog_item);
    });    
} else {
    //respond in html
    //console.log('Request made from browser adress bar, not through Angular, serving index page...');
    res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html');    
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an angular issue. When a user enters mydomain.com/get/data they never actually load up the angular app, so your solution must be done elsewhere.

For example, you could add this to your website's .htaccess file. It will redirect all traffic to the root of your domain.

Check out this answer here:
[.htaccess Redirect based on HTTP_REFERER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618445/htaccess-redirect-based-on-http-referer)

Comment: Would this still allow async Angular request to get my data from within the app?

Comment: Good point. I don't think it would. I've edited my answer. Check out the link above. The example given there is closer to what you need. I believe it will allow through requests as long as the referrer is on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @HankScorpio

Angular UI routing for Angular application paths and server application accessing URL paths are two different things.

Angular UI router allows you to navigate within a single page application as if you have a multi page application. This is in no way similar to accessing the actual server application endpoint.

All restrictions should be done on the web server and server web application end. Hence you will have to implement some authentication/authorisation strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Your angular code is running on their machine, in their browser.

As such, one can spoof the environment, capture the data as the browser requests it, edit the JS of your app while it is in their browser, or various other methods.

Why do you want such a restriction anyway?